# How to get Shopify API programmatically

Tags: react-native, shopify-api

I'm building a React Native app with Shopify integration issues.
After creating a private app in the Shopify admin panel, I need help getting the Shopify API programmatically.

You will need the Shopify API URL ([Example URL in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa0X9.png)) to receive your Shopify product. To create an API URL, Shopify users need to add an API key and API password and host name manually on the React Native app.

I have done this feature, but it is very inconvenient for users.
That's why I need to get the API URL programmatically after the user logs into Shopify with email and password in WebView.

I thought I could get the API URL by web scraping after the user login Shopify.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as using your shop name in the URL, such as shopname.myshopify.com.  But the best thing you can do is click the copy button on the Example URL field and use the full example URL so you know there are no errors.

Unfortunately, Shopify obscures this field because the apikey and password are so long.  When you look at the field, it isn't clear they provided you with a complete and working URL.

Good luck[image: Shopify Admin API Config]